# Your app includes SDK com.my.tracker:mytracker-sdk or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-developers-console

I get This Alert from google console for My app that made in Unity 2019.4.5f1 what should I do To Fix This ?

( Your app ***** version code ** includes SDK com.my.tracker:mytracker-sdk or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on, which collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Advertising ID, Android ID, Device Wifi MAC identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the User Data policy.

Starting from November 6, 2022 midnight (UTC), new app releases containing the SDK version(s) that do not comply with the User Data policy may be blocked from release. You may consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK that does not include the violating code if available from your SDK provider, or removing this SDK from your app.

ACTION REQUIRED: Upload a new compliant version AND deactivate the noncompliant version.

Read through the User Data policy for more details, and how to submit an updated app for review here.

If you've reviewed the policy and feel our decision may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team.  )
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using MyTarget SDK or any mediation that implement MyTarget SDK? MyTarget SDK depend on MyTracker SDK that causes the issue. Your app has to update MyTracker SDK to v3.0.9 or higher.

- If your app only implement MyTarget SDK, then check if the current version of your MyTarget SDK depend on MyTracker v3.0.9 or higher. Check here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.my.target/mytarget-sdk, if it writes [3.0.0,3.1.0) then resync dependencies to update to the newest version of MyTracker; if not then update MyTarget to a new version.
- If your app implement MyTracker SDK then update to the newest version of MyTracker.

Relevant GitHub issue page: https://github.com/myTargetSDK/mytarget-android/issues/18

Comment: how to know which version is my app implement ? because i didn't implement any of these by myself

Comment: are you using MyTarget SDK or any mediation that implement MyTarget SDK?

Comment: i found that (yodo1.mas sdk) is using mytarget-sdk
version 5.15 as its shows in this page https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.yodo1.mas.mediation/mytarget/4.7.3/aar

Comment: if your question has been answered then please mark the answer

Comment: i didn't find out how to fix it yet

Comment: I've already written how to fix it and how it work:

> check if the current version of your MyTarget SDK depend on MyTracker v3.0.9 or higher. Check here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.my.target/mytarget-sdk, if it writes [3.0.0,3.1.0) then resync dependencies to update to the newest version of MyTracker; if not then update MyTarget to a new version.

Comment: It seems you don't know how dependency versioning works. I'll check it for you.

Your mytarget sdk version is 5.15.1.0, which depend on mytracker v3.0.x. 

Which means you don't have to change anything, just build your apk again so it resync your dependency and it will automatically resolve to the newest version 3.0.9, which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using the latest version of [My Tracker SDK](https://github.com/myTrackerSDK/mytracker-unity/releases) after updating it try to upload your app again on the play store and see if that fixes your issue, if not then continue with other fixes mentioned in this answer.

You need to update the `privacy and security information` for your app on Play Store. `My Tracker` created a [checklist](https://tracker.my.com/docs/quick-start/checklist)(Check the second point in this checklist) that you can follow to successfully integrate it and release your app on Play Store and App store.

Use Full Links:

1. [Chicklist](https://tracker.my.com/docs/quick-start/checklist)
2. [What to update for Google Play Data safety](https://tracker.my.com/docs/privacy-and-security/google-data-safety)

Comment: Thank You For Replying To me , But you can say i'm confused or not sure how to do this , could you explain it to me more ?

Comment: @sayedkotb which version of My Tracker SDK are you using?

Comment: @ YogeshBen  i guess one of my libraries depends on my tracker sdk because i didn't install it in unity but i used 3rd plugins like (yodo1 mas sdk (for ads)- google play review sdk- google play review app update sdk- google play game services sdk- facebook sdk) but i don't know how to find it